# How do I make a Random not repeat itself on VBA for Powerpoint?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm doing a raffle of words on PowerPoint VBA, but I would like to know how do I make the random not repeat itself and possibly stop when all words were used?
Thank you since then and I wanna give all the credits to the person that created that macro.

CODE I USED

```vb
    Dim x As New Collection

        Sub box()
        Dim items() As String
        Dim y As Long

        items = Split("Blinding\ Nightmare\ Ice cream\", "\")
        For y = 0 To UBound(items)
        x.Add (items(y))
        Next y
        End Sub

        Sub wordspick()
        Dim words As Long
        Randomize
        y = Int(Rnd * x.Count) + 1
        Shapes("x").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = x(y)
        x.Remove (y)
        End Sub
```

Comment: Your posted code doesn't run as-is. Here's how to create a minimum reproducible example.: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. The _Randomize_ statement should be enough to ensure _Rnd_ doesn't repeat itself.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Dim x As Collection

Sub box()
    Dim items() As String
    Dim y As Long
    
    Set x = New Collection 'clear x, in case not empty
    items = Split("Blinding\Nightmare\Ice cream", "\")
    For y = 0 To UBound(items)
        x.Add items(y)
    Next y
    Randomize
End Sub

Sub wordspick()
    Dim words As Long, y As Long
    
    If Not x Is Nothing Then 'check collection is initialized
        If x.Count = 0 Then
            Debug.Print "No more words!" 'collection is empty
        Else
            y = Int(Rnd * x.Count) + 1
            'Shapes("x").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = x(y)
            Debug.Print x(y)
            x.Remove y
        End If
    End If
    
End Sub
```